# How can I find the order of growth of this recurrence: $T(n) =\sqrt{n}T\bigl(\sqrt{n}\bigr) + n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I am trying to find the order of growth ($O(n)$, $O(n\log n)$) of the recurrence $T(n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot T\bigl(\sqrt{n}\bigr) + n$.

I started to unroll the recurrence and found that I can rewrite it in the form:

$$T(n) = n^{\frac{2^k - 1}{2^k}}\cdot T(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}}) + kn$$

My with the thought of solving the equation $n^{\frac{1}{2^k}} = 1$ in terms of $k$ and thus finding the value of the recurrence.

The problem is that $k = \infty $, which leads me to the thought that I went to the wrong direction.

How can I find the solution for this recurrence.

**P.S.** I know that the solution is $O(n \cdot \log \log n)$, but I do not want to start with it.

**P.S.2** This is not a homework, just trying to refresh my math knowledge for analysis of recurrences in programming.

Comment: Rigorously speaking, the recurrence can not reach number $1$ in any finite number of steps (taking repeated square roots is going to get closer and closer to $1$, but never get to it), so your $k=\infty$ is correct (of course, in actual usage, we usually take floor of the square root, rather than the exact square root -- which makes it terminate rather quickly). Your approach can be salvaged by choosing a different stopping point instead of $1$, e.g. $2$ and just plug the value of $T(2)$ you find by any other means when you need it.

Comment: A different approach is to consider slightly different function: $S(n)=T(n)/n$ and find that it satisfies recurrence $S(n)=S(\sqrt{n})+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Peter's comment, I found the solution: $T(n) = n^{\frac{2^k - 1}{2^k}}\cdot T(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}}) + kn$.

Using not 1, but 2 as the stopping point: $n^{\frac{1}{2^k}} = 2$, which means that $k = \log \log n$.

Putting it back to the equation:
$T(n) = n^{\frac{\log n - 1}{\log n}}\cdot T(2) + n \log \log n$, which means that the order of growth is $O(n \log \log n)$